# foreign key reference issue. But why?

Tags: sql, sql-server

below is my er-diagram.
[image: ER Diagram]

My requirement is a customer can have a bundle of blouse / pardi / lhenga or any two or any 1 of the product.

For the above, below is my ER-DIAGRAM. but the problem is I am unable to create data from sql server. It says.

[image: Error]

below is the relation as requested:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MEASURE_TYPE]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_BLOUSE_MEASUREMENT] FOREIGN KEY([MEASUREMENTID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[BLOUSE_MEASUREMENT] ([MEASUREMENTID])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MEASURE_TYPE] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_BLOUSE_MEASUREMENT]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MEASURE_TYPE]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_CUSTOMER] FOREIGN KEY([CUSTOMERID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[CUSTOMER] ([CUSTOMERID])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MEASURE_TYPE] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_CUSTOMER]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MEASURE_TYPE]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_LHENGA_MEASUREMENT] FOREIGN KEY([MEASUREMENTID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[LHENGA_MEASUREMENT] ([MEASUREMENTID])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MEASURE_TYPE] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_LHENGA_MEASUREMENT]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MEASURE_TYPE]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_PARDI_MEASUREMENT] FOREIGN KEY([MEASUREMENTID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[PARDI_MEASUREMENT] ([MEASUREMENTID])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MEASURE_TYPE] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_PARDI_MEASUREMENT]
GO
```

[image: relation_fk]

Comment: Can you share the `FK_BLOUSE_MEASUREMENT` constraint details?

Comment: This does not show the FK. From the object explorer, select the table -> keys -> (For each FK_) Right click -> Script key as -> Create To -> New query window -> Copy-paste it here. Please don't use screenshots here , because we can't copy the text.

Comment: oh ok. let me paste it here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `FK_BLOUSE_MEASUREMENT` constraint is on the `MEASURE_TYPE` table. You are trying to insert into `MEASURE_TYPE` a record for `BLOUSE_MEASUREMENT` without doing the corresponding insert in the `BLOUSE_MEASUREMENT`. You are inserting a `measurementid` in `MEASURE_TYPE` for which `measurementid` with same value is not present in `BLOUSE_MEASUREMENT` table.

First do the insert in `BLOUSE_MEASUREMENT` and then in `MEASURE_TYPE`.

**UPDATE**

Because you use the same row as foreign key for multiple tables, DB expects the `measurementid` to be present in all measurement tables. You will need foriegn keys per measurement table in `MEASURE_TYPE`.

So `MEASURE_TYPE` will have following columns: `Blouse_measurement_id`, `Pardi_measurement_id`, `Lhenga_measurement_id`, `ordertype`, `customerid`. And  foreign key constraint from `Blouse_measurement_id` to `measurementid` in `BLOUSE_MEASUREMENT` and similarly for other tables.

Comment: i am doing the same, while inserting in measure_type table, it then says, the fk_pardi_measurement error pop up.

Comment: have inserted a row in BLOUSE_MEASUREMENT, PARDI_MEASUREMENT,LHENGA_MEASURMENT. THEN I INSERT A ROW IN MEASURE_TYPE AGAINST THE MEASUREMENTID. THEN IT SAYS. FK_PARDI_MEASUREMENT

Comment: so what do i do? i have already inserted 3 records in the blouse, lhenga and measurement table with different measurement ids..

Comment: i will have to delete the relation with the measurement_type and then insert the records for the lhenga, pardi and blouse ..

Answer (score 0):

From your ER diagram I guess that FK_BLOUSE_MEASUREMENT is targeting MEASURE_TYPE.MEASUREMENTID.

Are you trying to insert into table BLOUSE_MEASUREMENT without having inserted a row with the same MEASUREMENTID in table MEASURE_TYPE?

Comment: I have inserted a row in BLOUSE_MEASUREMENT, PARDI_MEASUREMENT,LHENGA_MEASURMENT. 
THEN I INSERT A ROW IN MEASURE_TYPE AGAINST THE MEASUREMENTID. THEN IT SAYS. FK_PARDI_MEASUREMENT

Comment: You always have to fill first the row of the FK target, then the source. As Rohit says, send us the code of your FKs so we can deduce the problem.

Comment: yes as said, the fk target tables were blouse_measurement, pardi_measurement.lhenga_measurement. I inserted a row in all the 3 tables first.